# easy but confusing

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Good evening everyone , I'm new in the forum my teacher challenged me with this question:
count the number of class of similarity of $M_n(C)$ whose elements have characterstic polynomial equal to $(X-a_1)^{n_1} .... (X-a_r)^{n_r}$ where $a_i$ are distincts two by two , and the $n_i$ are in $N^*$
I tried to use the jordan form but how to finish it ?

Comment: What does *"$a_i$ are distincts two by two"* mean?

Comment: the roots of teh polynomial

Comment: No one ? :( it's just a problem of combinatorics , it does just need an explanation ? someone could give a complete proof ?

Comment: I still don't know what *"$a_i$ are distincts two by two"* is supposed to mean

Comment: the " $a_i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix they are different two by two(sorry I'm french , my english is bad)

Comment: Okay, the phrase "different two by two" doesn't translate well, so it was throwing me off.  In fact, "two by two" made me think of $2 \times 2$ matrices.  I see now that you mean that for all $i \neq j$, $a_i \neq a_j$.  In English, we say "pairwise distinct" (so you were close).

Comment: Ah I see , can you give more details about your proof sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking what I *think* you're asking, then the answer is that there are 
$\prod_{i=1}^rp(n_i)$ many distinct similarity classes of matrices that have a given characteristic polynomial (where the $a_i$ are distinct complex numbers).

Here, $p(n)$ denotes the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function).

---

Note that each matrix with this characteristic polynomial is similar to some $J$ Jordan form with the correct multiplicity of eigenvalues.  In particular, $A$ is similar to *exactly one* matrix of the form $J = \bigoplus_{i=1}^r J_i$ where
$$
J_i = \bigoplus_{j=1}^{p_i} J_{q_j}(a_i)
$$
such for each $i$, we have $q_1 + \cdots + q_{p_i} = n_i$ and $q_1 \geq q_2 \geq \cdots \geq q_{p_i}$.

To count the number of permissible $J_i$, it suffices to count the number of descending sequences $(q_1,q_2,\dots,q_{p_i})$ such that $q_1 + \cdots + q_{p_i} = n_i$.  However, this is precisely $p(n_i)$.

To count the number of permissible $J$, note that we may independently select each $J_i$.  Thus, we reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: yes that's the answer I found but can you give a detailed proof please sir

Comment: I really need a complete proof , I've been working in that problem for two days

Comment: I've put some more of the steps in.  By my standards, this is a complete proof.  However, let me know if there is a step that requires clarification.

Comment: Thanks sir , elegant proof :) do you have similar problems ?

Comment: @Seginus a classic one: prove that for every matrix $A$, there exists a matrix $X$ such that $e^X = A$.  Here, $e^X$ is the matrix exponential, which is to say
$$
e^X = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}X^n
$$
prove that this is **not** true if we impose the condition $A \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ and $X \in M_n(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: $A$ should be nonsingular ?

Comment: @Seginus yes! $A$ should be non-singular, I forgot to say so.